# vim replace a string when a change occurred in another place

Tags: vim

Say, I have a file:

```
Program foo
 <program text>
End Program foo
```

Is it possible that if I change the word `foo` in the first line to `bar` (which may not be the first line of the file), the last line's `foo` will also be changed to `bar` automatically?

Comment: I can't help thinking that (much as I love vim) that a source-aware IDE is what you're really wanting here

Comment: True....but if an IDE has it, there must be a way in vim also.....for a filetype

Comment: The point I'm making is that an IDE would be much more aware of the source structure/syntax tree etc. e.g. Intellij is aware of Java syntax in a deep way that vim is not

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global command and a find and replace to mark the start en stop of the area that should be replace like this

```
:g/^Program foo$/.,/foo$/s//bar
```

**Breakdown**

```
:g                    Starts the global command
/^Program foo$        Search for Program foo where the line starts with Program and ends with foo
/.,/foo$/             for each mach, expand the rang until the next foo at the end of the line
s//bar                substitute your last search results with bar
```

Comment: It does have it's wrinkels. A more foolproof version would be `g/^\zsProgram foo$/.,/Program foo$/s/Program \zsfoo/bar` but that's to hard to get right right away.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do such things as follows:

- move the cursor over the name to be changed
- press `*` or `#` (this searches for this word forwards or backwards, respectively, and *only* for the word as a whole, so in your example only `foo` occurrences were found, not `foobar` or `myfoo`)
- change the name: `caw<new name><ESC>`
- repeat until done: press `n` to jump to the next possible occurrence, press `.` to repeat the name changing operation if required

You could also use a single search-and-replace command like `:%s/\<foo\>/new_name/gc` and then press `y` or `n` for every `foo` occurrence, but personally I prefer the above method because it saves me from typing `foo` and from remembering to put `\<` and `\>` around it (`#`/`*` do this for me).

If you are sure that you want to replace *all* occurrences of `foo` to `bar`, you can omit the `c`onfirm flag from the search-and-replace command, which will then be the shortest way to do what you want that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin out, i think it would exactly what you want:

https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cursor is on the program name this can be done pretty easily.

1. Change program name:

   ```
   ciW
   foobar<Esc>
   ```
2. Move to end of program:

   ```
   /End<CR>
   $
   ```
3. Repeat change:

   ```
   .
   ```