# python code in vim script

Tags: python, vim

I have a file, say:

```
Program  foo
Implicit None
integer::ab
End Program bar
```

Now, I want the "bar" in last line to be "foo" (i.e. Program and End program name should be same). 
I wrote a `python` script for this, which works very well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
with open("i.f90") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        if line.startswith("Program"):
            var = line.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1].strip()
        if line.startswith("End Program"):
            v2 = line.strip()
            print v2
inp.close()
STR="End Program "+var
print STR
for line in fileinput.input("i.f90", inplace=True):
    print line.replace(v2, STR).strip()
```

But, as I want to call it from `vim`, as a `ftplugin`, I put it in vim's ftplugin as:

```
function! Edname() 
python<<EOF
import vim
import fileinput
with open("i.f90") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        if line.startswith("Program"):
            var = line.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1].strip()
        if line.startswith("End Program"):
            v2 = line.strip()
            print v2
inp.close()
STR="End Program "+var
print STR
for line in fileinput.input("i.f90", inplace=True):
    print line.replace(v2, STR).strip()
EOF
endfunction
```

As you can see the only changes I have made is to put it in vim. No real change in the actual python code. But in this case, this is not working. It is printing the `v2` and `STR` properly, but the line in the file (or the buffer) 
is not getting updated.

Any clue?

This is largely to do with [my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000853/vim-replace-a-string-when-a-change-occurred-in-another-place). 
But now, I have find a partial solution with `python`, but that is not working when called from vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's what you mean by *automation*, you don't need Python.  Just put something like this in a `ftplugin` for your filetype:

```
function! s:FixName()
    let [buf, l, c, off] = getpos('.')
    call cursor([1, 1, 0])

    let lnum = search('\v\c^Program\s+', 'cnW')
    if !lnum
        call cursor(l, c, off)
        return
    endif

    let parts = matchlist(getline(lnum), '\v\c^Program\s+(\S*)\s*$')
    if len(parts) < 2
        call cursor(l, c, off)
        return
    endif

    let lnum = search('\v\c^End\s+Program\s+', 'cnW')
    call cursor(l, c, off)
    if !lnum
        return
    endif

    call setline(lnum, substitute(getline(lnum), '\v\c^End\s+Program\s+\zs.*', parts[1], ''))
endfunction

call s:FixName()
```

You can also do it with a macro, but that doesn't look as clever as the function above. ;) Something like this:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <C-p> /\v\c^Program\s+\zs<CR>"zy$/\v\c^End\s+Program\s+\zs<CR>D"zP
```

Comment: I tried that (a blind copy; cant claim I have understood that), but `:call s:FixName()` gives me error:
`E41: Using <SID> not in a script context`

Comment: @BaRud As I said: "put [it] in a `ftplugin` for your filetype" (the `ftplugin` will call the function when you first open your file).  Or write it to a file `foo.vim` and source it from the current file: `:so foo.vim`.  Or drop the `s:` from the function name if you absolutely must call it manually.

Comment: Thanks...its working perfectly now. But, as I said, I hardly understood it, can I use an arg in it, and, say, work as:
`lnum = search('\v\c^a:arg\s+', 'cnW')`?
I tried, but this is not working

Comment: @BaRud The script addresses your question the way you asked it.  If you want to modify it, I believe you're supposed to ask a new question.  However, I'd say a better way for you would be to start with macro at the end of my post and understand that.  It doesn't do anything tricky, really.

Comment: when time permits, may you kindly have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022184/vim-search-or-match-pattern-with-variables
This is the new question as you asked.